# Angular 6 : Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-httpclient

I have a component loading a local json file (contains only name) from assets folder.Since HttpClient takes care of formatting data as json, so didn't use map here.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators'

 export type cont= {name: string};

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    1st List
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let contact of contacts | async">{{contact.name}}</li>
    </ul>
    2st List
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let contact of contacts2 | async">{{contact.name}}</li>
    </ul>
    `
})
export class AppComponent {;
  contacts: Observable<cont[]>;
  contacts2: Observable<cont[]>;
  constructor (http: HttpClient) {
    this.contacts = http.get<cont[]>('http://localhost:4200/assets/contacts.json');               
    setTimeout(() => this.contacts2 = this.contacts, 500);
  }
}
```

Contacts.json

```
 {
"items": [
  { "name": "Mark Twain" },
  { "name": "Sherlock Holmes" }
]
```

}

Data can be fetched on browser via http://localhost:4200/assets/contacts.json but When I tried to render the same via async pipe I get this error below.Tried many ways to convert observable  to Observable<[]> but none passed this scenario. **What's wrong here. how json data over httpclient can be converted to Array ?** (***tried to follow similar posts but none helped***)?

[image: Error]

Comment: http.get returns a Promise.

Comment: are you able to log this.contacts2 or this.contacts?

Comment: At all costs avoid using `setTimeout()`, you will not be able to control how quickly the response will resolve and that is exactly why RxJS operators such as `map()` exist, even just to extract data from nested properties.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky: Thanks. I also don't intend to use it. hands on stuff.

Answer (score 7):

You are trying to iterate over an object:

```
{
  "items": [
    { "name": "Mark Twain" },
    { "name": "Sherlock Holmes" }
  ]
}
```

You should iterate over `contacts.items`

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let contact of (contacts | async)?.items">{{contact.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

or just use observable map:

```
const url = 'http://localhost:4200/assets/contacts.json';
this.contacts = http.get<cont[]>(url).pipe(map(data => data.items));
```

**ANOTHER SOLUTION using `Symbol.iterator`**

I am adding it just because it is interesting (in my opinion) approach although not practical in this case.

I can leave iteration over an asynchronous object:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let contact of contacts | async">{{contact.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

but I will convert this object to iterable by adding [iterable protocol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols):

```
const url = 'http://localhost:4200/assets/contacts.json';
this.contacts = http.get<cont[]>(url).pipe(
  map((data: any) => {
    data[Symbol.iterator] = () => data.items[Symbol.iterator]();
    return data;
  })
);
```

The line

```
data[Symbol.iterator] = () => data.items[Symbol.iterator]()
```

redirects iteration over the object (which is impossible by default) to iteration over its `items` array.

I created a [STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-scrjz1?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) demonstrating this

Comment: Thanks !!. Could you elaborate it a bit `http.get<{[key:string]: cont[]}>(url).pipe(map(data => data.items)); ` please ?

Comment: Since I did not see any interface or type for your object, I just said that the output of your get request will be an object with any string key ('items' in your case). But actually, after the map we will return an array only, so I will update my answer and return your original type

Comment: tried it out, data is being logged both ways and rendered too. but with `let contact of (contacts | async).items">{{contact.name}}' I get **`ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'items' of null`** at browser though data is rendered.

Comment: just add safe null operator `?` (https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#the-safe-navigation-operator----and-null-property-paths): `<li *ngFor="let contact of (contacts | async)?.items">{{contact.name}}</li>`. I updated my answer as well.

Comment: I added additional solution using `Symbol.iterator`, Please check my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

**this will surely work just define varible correctly**

this happens when data json you have in the variable is not in the array format.define  variable like this

```
 contacts:[] and store the json from api like this:-
    response = http.get<cont[]>('http://localhost:4200/assets/contacts.json'); 
    this.contacts= response.items //array start from items key

    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let contact of contacts">{{contact.name}}</li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: `response` in your example will be an `observable` returned by `http` which does not have `items` property. Use `rxjs`'s `map` function to accomplish this. Please see my answer above regarding `map` function